# Mongo converting timestamp to date

Tags: mongodb, unix-timestamp, to-date

Im still new in mongo but i have a data in mongo collection that is structured like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f79931104a8f102f761398e"),
    "data1" : "This is a data",
    "data2" : "This is a data",
    "timeStampVar" : Timestamp(1603377200, 0),
},
```

Currently i am trying to grab data in the last 14 Days using the timeStampVar. So far my code are like this:

```
var yesterdayStart = new Date();
yesterdayStart.setDate(yesterdayStart.getDate() - 14);
yesterdayStart.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);


var yesterdayEnd = new Date();
yesterdayEnd.setDate(yesterdayEnd.getDate() - 1);
yesterdayEnd.setUTCHours(23,59,59,999);

db.collection_name.aggregate([{ 
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {"$toDate": "$timeStampVar"}
    }
  },

  { 
    "$match": {
        "date": { $gte: yesterdayStart, $lte: yesterdayEnd},
      }
  },

])
```

I'm encountering issue when trying to use the $toDate to convert my 10-digit timestamp into a date object. As it says this :

```
{
    "message" : "Unsupported conversion from timestamp to date in $convert with no onError value",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 241,
    "codeName" : "ConversionFailure",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

Am i missing something here?. On the mongo documentation of $toDate i see that the examples are using 13-digit timestamp could it be that it does not support a 10-digit timestamp? 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever one has to work with Date/Time values in javascript then I recommend [Moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library. It makes your life much easier.

Would be like this:

```
{ 
 "$match": {
    "date": { 
       $gte: moment().subtract(14,'days'),startOf('day').toDate(),
       $lte: moment().subtract(1,'days'),endOf('day').toDate(),
    },
  }
}
```

Have a look at [Timestamps](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps):

> Note
>
> The BSON `timestamp` type is for ***internal*** MongoDB use. For most cases, in application development, you will want to use the BSON `date` type. See [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) for more information.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer , Since im new in mongo is it a best practice to store time in Mongo using Date object instead of UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Yes, that's what I have stated. If your application has only UNIX timestamp then use like `new Date(timestamp * 1000)`